# Create lists of permutations of size N from elements of another list

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

How do I, given a List = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)], N = 2, create a list containing the multiple ordered permutations of List, size N:

`permutations([(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)],2,ListOut).
 ListOut=[[(1,1),(1,2)],[(1,1),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,4)],[(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,2),(1,4)],[(1,3),(1,4)]]`

??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DanielLyons I don't know how to do it in Prolog, I did it in C, which is quite easy. Prolog has permutations, but I don't know if I can/how to use it in a smaller size than the original structure. Meaning, that I could clearly use permutations on my original List and then select the first N elements of the permutated lists and that would be it, but how do I do it in Prolog?

Comment: You could restrict it to the size you want by specifying a list of unknowns using `length/2`: `length(Permutation, 2), permutation(List, Permutation).` assuming you have a `permutation/2` that does what you want.

Comment: That permutation/2 is the problem :b

Comment: There are lots of solutions; you can look at lots of existing questions to see how you can do it, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366638/prolog-permutation-function).

Answer (score 3):

First let's solve the problem of finding **one** permutation:

```
perm(_, 0, []).
perm([X|Xs], N, [X|Ys]) :- N1 is N-1, perm(Xs,N1,Ys).
perm([_|Xs], N, Y) :- N>0, perm(Xs,N,Y).
```

There are two recursive rules: 1) `X` can be the first element of the output, and find the remaining permutation of `N-1` for the rest of the list; 2) skip the first element, and find the permutation over the remaining elements of the input list.

Finding all permutations is just about using `findall/3`:

```
permutations(X, N, Y) :- findall(Z, perm(X, N, Z), Y).
```

Test:

```
?- permutations([(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)], 2, X).
```

> X = [[(1, 1),  (1, 2)], [(1, 1),  (1, 3)], [(1, 1),  (1, 4)], [(1, 2),  (1, 3)], [(1, 2),  (1, 4)], [(1, 3),  (1, 4)]].

Comment: Why do you need the cut?

Comment: The cut is "needed" for termination because the second clause does not have a guard `N > 0`. That guard would be a better idea than the cut.

Comment: The cut was not really needed. I needed to add the condition `N>0` in the last rule to avoid generating the same result in multiple ways. (now fixed)